# Where am I wrong in my understanding about the activeness of the constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have following convex optimization problem $$\text{min.      }~~ x~\\ \text{s.t.}~~~\frac{y^2}{x}\leq z\\ y+z\leq c$$ where $\{x,y,z\}$ are the non-negative variables and $c$ is some positive constant. I think in the optimal solution both of the constraints should be active due to following reasoning.

1- Suppose that for the optimal solution we have $\{x^*,y^*,z^*\}$ and we consider the following possibilities

1a- First constraint is not active. Then we can decrease $x$ (hence reducing the objective function) to make the constraint active and hence $\{x^*,y^*,z^*\}$ is not the optimal solution.

1b- Second constraint is not active. In this case, we can increase $z$ to make the right hand side of first constraint bigger and subsequently we can reduce $x$ to reduce the objective function.

Based on above reasoning, I think, both of the constraints should be active. However, when I solve the above problem through cvx in MATLAB I see that the constraints are not active. Where am I wrong in my understanding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is right. However, you have overseen that you can choose $y$ arbitrarily small when $x$ approaches 0. Therefore, the constraints will not be met with equality.

For example, you may choose $z=c/2, y = x/2$. Then assume $x$ goes towards 0.

- The second constraint will be met as $y + z = x/2 + c/2 < c$ when $x$ is small enough
- The first constrain will be met as $\frac{y^2}{x} = x/4 < z = c/2$ when $x$ is small enough.

Consequently, we have the solution $x^\star \rightarrow 0 $ of the optimization problem.

Comment: There is more to that. CVX is a bit 'lying' - the problem does not have an optimal solution at all. Its optimal value, the infimum, is $0$, but there is no feasible solution which attains it. However, CVX has no way of knowing that no optimal value exists, and it attempts to approach is as best as it can.

Comment: @AlexShtof To be more precise cvx will reformulate the second constraint as $xz\geq y^2, x,y\geq 0$ (rotated quadratic cone) and then 0 is the optimal and attained solution to that reformulation.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, it is indeed true. But the original problem, before reformulation, does not have an optimal solution. I think that this is exactly what the OP was missing.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some slack variables $\epsilon_i$ we can build the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda,\epsilon) = x-\lambda_1\left(\frac{y^2}{x}-z+\epsilon_1^2\right)+\lambda_2(y+z-c+\epsilon_2^2) + \lambda_3(x-\epsilon_3^2)+\lambda_4(y-\epsilon_4^2)+\lambda_5(z-\epsilon_5^2)
$$

solving the stationary points for

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

we obtain the solution

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
x&y&z&\epsilon_1^2&\epsilon_2^2&\epsilon_3^2&\epsilon_4^2&\epsilon_5^2& x\\
-4c&2c&-c&0&0&-4c&2c&-c&-4c\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

which shows us that the only feasible solution is for $c = 0$ because $\epsilon_i^2 \ge 0$